# Writing the symbol degrees celsius in axis titles with R/plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to write the symbol degrees celsius with R/Plotly in one of my titles. It works when I just use a simple plot a below:

```
# Working code
library(latex2exp)
set.seed(1)  
betas <- rnorm(1000)
hist(betas, main = TeX("Temperature (^0C)"))
```

However, when I try to run the code through plotly, I get the following error: "unimplemented type 'expression' in 'HashTableSetup'".

```
#Initialise the plot
p <- plot_ly()

#Add axis names
#Font
f <- list(
  family = "Courier New, monospace",
  size = 18,
  color = "#7f7f7f")

#X axis name
x <- list(
  title = "x Axis",
  titlefont = f)


#Y Axis name
y <- list(
  title =  TeX("Temperature (^0C)"),
  titlefont = f)

#Add layout
p <- p %>%
  layout(xaxis = x, yaxis= y)

p
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found a hacky solution: Look for the special character on google and copy and paste it directly in the R code.

```
#Y Axis name
y <- list(
  title = "Temperature (°C)",
  titlefont = f)
```

I'm still interested in a less hacky solution which allows to insert LaTeX into Plotly.

Answer (score 41):

Try,

```
title =  "Temperature (\u00B0C)"
```

Comment: This solution also works for the ASCII character requirement of the R package check function. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Try `title  = expression("Temperature ("*~degree*C*")")` or `title = "Temperature (°C)"`